# How to swap eth and btc to bsc using binance bridge api and transfer bsc to another account using binance api?

Tags: c#, binance, binance-smart-chain

For eth swap I used

```
 POST api.binance.org/bridge/api/v2/swaps
```

with body

```
   {
    "amount": 0.2,
    "direction": "IN",
    "fromNetwork": "ETH",
    "source":"",
    "symbol":"ETH",
    "toAddress":"my wallet address",
    "toAddressLabel":"",
    "toNetwork":"BSC",
    "walletAddress": "my wallet address",
    "walletNetwork": "ETH"
 }
```

This gave me a deposit Address. How can I deposit a test token to that address to avoid using real crypto for test.

I tried depositing test token from infura using c# Netherium web3 library to test. But Test token decreases but binance test token doesnot increases.